# Permutations, cycles and conjugacy

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $u \in S_n$ be a cycle, where $S_n$ is the group of permutations of the set with $n$ elements. Let $\sigma \in S_n$ such that the support of $\sigma \circ u \circ \sigma^{-1}$ is the same as the support of $u$. Does this imply that $u$ commutes with $\sigma$ ?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suppose that this is true? If so, it would be probably be useful to describe this, even if only briefly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the support of $\sigma$ is $\{x \mid \sigma(x) \neq x\}$.

With that in mind, let $S_4$ act on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and take $\sigma = (1\; 2),$ $u = (1\; 2\; 3)$. Then the support of $u$ is $\{1,2,3\}$.

$\sigma u \sigma^{-1} = (1\; 3\; 2) \neq u$, so $u$ and $\sigma$ don't commute, and the support of $\sigma u \sigma^{-1}$ is $\{1,2,3\}$ also.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I kind of realized shortly after posting that it would be almost surely false, but you beat me to finding a counterexample